# Detect if server is up and running after iis reset - powershell / sharepoint

Tags: 2013, powershell, warm-up

I'm having a warmup script that I want to run after an Update-SPSolution

```
foreach( $file in $solutionsxml.Solutions.Solution) 
{
    $filename = $file.name;

    Write-Host "  Updating:" $filename

    Update-SPSolution -LiteralPath "$localpath$filename" -Identity $filename -GACDeployment
}

. .\warmup.ps1
```

what's the best way to detect that the server is up and running? (before executing the warmup script?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally do something like this, for a specific solution (so in your case it will be put in the `foreach`:

```
$solution = get-SpSolution $fileName
while($solution.JobExists)
{
    start-sleep -s 5
    Write-Host -NoNewline "."
}

#Here you know the job is finished, and you can start your update
```

Comment: How do you get the "." in one line like ".." "..." (like a loding bar... )

Comment: You can use `Write-Host -NoNewline "."`

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the above.  Just another way to skin the cat:

```
$wsp = "my.solution.wsp"
write-host Waiting for new $wsp to deploy ...
$s = Get-SPSolution | where-object {$_.Name -eq $wsp} | select deployed
while ($s.Deployed -eq $false) { 
   sleep 3
   $s = Get-SPSolution | where-object {$_.Name -eq $wsp} | select deployed
   write-host -NoNewline .
}
write-host Completed deployment of $wsp
```